# How do I pass in my API key as an environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am using themoviedb-api ruby gem in rails 4 and I would like to keep my API key out of git so I though of passing it in as an environment variable. What is the correct syntax?

In my .env I have

```
TMDB_API_KEY=ee27f0e6fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

In my initializers/tmdb.rb I have

```
Tmdb::Api.key("KEY_HERE")
```

I have tried a few different ideas but nothing has worked. Like ENV['TMDB_API_KEY'] for example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you can't just stick things in `.env` and have them work. You'll need to use a gem like `dotenv`. https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

You can then access it using `ENV['VAR_NAME']`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of dotenv but I'm not sure if that will help in this instance as the gem does not seem to have :api_key as a configurable option. It seems one is required to put the api key in the initializer. I tried passing the ENV['TMDB_API_KEY'] inside the parenthesis but I get an invalid api error back from 'the movie db' Do you know what the correct syntax would be if I was to use your suggestion..

Comment: I just implemented your answer and installed the ruby gem dotenv and all is working thanks for the help Mr Woolf, your awesome!

Answer (score 0):

in `application.rb`:

```
config.before_configuration do
  env_file = Rails.root.join("config", "environment_variables.yml").to_s

  if File.exists?(env_file)
    YAML.load_file(env_file)[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
      ENV[key.to_s] = value
    end
  end
end
```

in `/config/environment_variables.yml`:

```
default: &default
    key: "development_key"

development:
    <<: *default

test:
    <<: *default

production:
    <<: *default
    key: "production_key"
```

anywhere in your code:
`ENV["key"]` should point to the right value for the current environment.